# Modified moving average for variable step information

Tags: algorithm, filtering, signal-processing

The **Modified Moving Average** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Modified_moving_average) is applied to data that is sampled at a fixed time step.  Is there a low pass filter that is like this that can be applied to data that is sampled with a variable time step?

Comment: Can't really make a good answer without knowing what this data is and why you need to filter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine that the value provided by each sample persists until the next sample, the signal becomes a continuous signal with a sequence of step changes at the sample times.

You can then apply the "modified moving average" filter to produce a continuous smoothed signal, and you can calculate the exact value of the the smoothed signal at any time with the formula:

y<sub>now</sub> = x<sub>prev</sub> + (y<sub>prev</sub> - x<sub>prev</sub>) * e<sup>-Rt</sup>

Where x<sub>prev</sub> is the preceding sample, y<sub>prev</sub> is the smoothed value at the time of the preceding sample (which would have been calculated with the same formula), t is the time since the preceding sample, and R is a factor between 0 and 1 that controls the amount of smoothing.  Smaller values of R make smoother outputs.

This is quite similar to the formula that @btilly gives, but he uses x<sub>now</sub> instead of x<sub>prev</sub>, which may work for you but doesn't have the same interpretation as a filtered continuous signal.

Comment: This and @btilly's information was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Like this" is subjective.  Here are two approaches that may work for you.

The first is to use interpolation to turn your data with variable time steps into data with fixed time steps and then use a moving average.  If your variable time steps exactly match the fixed time steps then this becomes the exponentially damped moving average.

The second is to let `r` be the log of the desired decay rate.  (It will be a negative number.)  Then if your next observation is at time `t` after your previous one, then:

```
average_next = average_old * e^(r*t) + (1 - e^(r*t))*observation
```

Assuming that `r*t` is small, you can just use a couple of terms of the well-known Taylor series `e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + ...`.

This calculation is more complex, but again if the variable steps are fixed, then this turns into the moving average.  (And you don't need an exact match to make it work!)

Comment: Note that this method has some strange properties that may or may not be OK, like when the previous sample is old, then the output will get very close to a new sample right away.  When the previous sample is recent, it will not.  (x,y) = [(0,0), (10,1)] produces a different result than [(0,0), (5,0), (10,1)]

Comment: @MattTimmermans That is true.  And the results of `[(0, 0), (5, 8), (6, 9), (7, 10)]` are strongly weighted to the `(5, 8)` data point.  Given that, the first is generally better.  Though the second is fine if you have regularish intervals but sometimes miss a measurement.